# Complex equation $|z|^6=\bar{z}^3+15z^3-64$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I need to solve the following complex equation:

$|z|^6=\bar{z}^3+15z^3-64$.

If I set $z=|z|e^{i\phi}$, I get

$|z|^6=|z|^3 e^{-i3\phi}+15|z|^3e^{i3\phi}-64$

For $\phi=0$ the solution is $z=2$. What is the reasoning to get other solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\overline{z}^{3} + 15z^{3}$ must be real. This means such expression equals its conjugate:
\begin{align*}
\overline{z}^{3} + 15z^{3} = z^{3} + 15\overline{z}^{3} & \Rightarrow z^{3} = \overline{z}^{3}
\end{align*}

Consequently, the proposed equation is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
|z|^{6} = 16z^{3} - 64 
\end{align*}

Finally, one obtains the desired solutions as follows:
\begin{align*}
|z|^{6} = 16z^{3} - 64 & \Longleftrightarrow (z\overline{z})^{3} = 16z^{3}- 64\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z^{3}\overline{z}^{3} - 16z^{3} + 64 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z^{6} - 16z^{3} + 64 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (z^{3} - 8)^{2} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z^{3} = 8\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z \in\left\{2,2\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{3}\right),2\exp\left(\frac{4\pi i}{3}\right)\right\}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: All three cube roots of $8$ are roots of the original equation, not just $z=2$. The question asks about obtaining the other roots.

Comment: @J.G. Indeed, my bad. I forgot to mention the other roots. Now I have fixed it. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

> We can eliminate either the term $\bar{z}^3$ or $z^3$ by the using the fact that $z\cdot \bar{z} = |z|^2$

$$
z^3 \cdot |z|^6 = z^3\cdot\bar{z}^3 + 15z^6 - 64z^3
\\\iff 15z^6 - (|z|^6 + 64)z^3 + |z|^6 = 0, \text{ which is quadratic in } z^3
\\\therefore z^3 = \dfrac{|z|^6 + 64 \pm \sqrt{(|z|^6 + 64)^2 - 4\cdot15\cdot|z|^6}}{30}
\\\text{Observe,} \,\, (|z|^6 + 64)^2 - 4\cdot15\cdot|z|^6 = (|z|^6 + 34)^2 + 2940 > 0
\\\text{Also notice,} \,\, |z|^6 + 64 = \sqrt{(|z|^6 + 64)^2} \ge \sqrt{(|z|^6 + 64)^2 - 4\cdot15\cdot|z|^6}
\\\bbox[yellow]{\therefore {z^3 \in \mathbb{R}^+ \implies \Re{(z^3)} > 0 \text{ and } \Im{(z^3)} = 0}}
\\\operatorname{Arg}{(z^3)} = 3\operatorname{Arg}{(z)} = -2\pi, 0, 2\pi
\\\therefore \operatorname{Arg}{(z)} = \dfrac{-2\pi}{3}, 0, \dfrac{2\pi}{3}
$$

Now, we use can $\operatorname{Arg}{(z)} = 0$ to evaluate $|z|$.

$$
|z|^6 = |z|^3 \cdot e^{0\cdot i} + 15|z|^3 \cdot e^{0\cdot i} - 64
\\\iff |z|^6 + 16|z|^3 - 64 = 0
\\\iff (|z|^3 - 8)^2 = 0
\\\iff |z| = 2
$$

Thus,

$$\bbox[5px, border: 2px solid black]{
z = -1 \pm i\sqrt{3}, \,\, z = 2
}
$$